# How to move ViewGroup when scrolling ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ViewGroup in top of Activity, 3 buttons and 3 ListView ( they are placed horizontally   ). When I scroll ListView from down to up, my buttons and ViewGroup should be scrolled accordingly, from down to up.

My question - how can I implement it? ( scrolling ViewGroup and buttons )

[image: example]

Updated: buttons scrolls ListViews left to right and right to left ( like tab bar ), but ViewGroup and button doesn't moves;

Answer (score 2):

`ListView` has very convenient method [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)). So put your `ViewGroup` and buttons into separate xml layout. Inflate view from this xml and add it to your `ListView` using `addHeaderView`.

Comment: Thx for idea! But one problem doesn't solved - by pressing buttons ListView should scrolls left to right and right to left. How can I do it with HeaderView?

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask another question - this is not relevant to the initial question you asked.

Comment: @Multix I agree with `notrix`. This is another question.

Comment: @Fox in socks, I am a new user on stackoverflow. What the best way to reask question - edit this question or ask new?

Comment: @Multix Definitely the better way is to create new one.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head:

1)Make a list adapter for the list view. This class must extend SimpleAdapter, BaseAdapter, etc.

2)Make a XML layout for the list`s item, that includes the buttons and other elements you may desire. (your_item_layout.xml). This layout implements a listview if you want.

3)The list adapter needs an data structure to storage information for the list view, like an ArrayList, Map, Array, etc. 
For example: private ArrayList al;

4)This list adapter function

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup vg){

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout,null);
/*set as you wish the elements of the item layout*/
Button b1 = v.findViewById(R.id.button1_item_layout);
b1.setText("OPEN FILE " + al.get(position));
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        /*do something*/
    }

});
}
```

I hope that helps!